# Keeping the local variables state when a delegate is created

Tags: c#, closures

So let's say I have this code:

```
Func<int>[] list = new Func<int>[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    list[i] = delegate
    {
        return i;
    };
}

foreach (var f in list) Console.WriteLine(f());
```

The output will be

```
4
4
4
4
```

because all the "i"s in the delegates point tot he same variable.

Is there any way to keep a copy of the state i was in when the delegate was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a separate variable inside the loop so that each delegate references its own copy in its closure.

Comment: Hey thanks! That works! By the way, my code does what I want when I write a JavaScript equivalent. What is the reasoning between these two languages behaving differently?

Comment: @LukaHorvat You'd have to post the javascript code because they should both capture the variable not the value. Are you reusing an index variable? Variables have function scope not block scope in javascript.

Comment: @LukaHorvat it's changing in C# 5.0 - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx) for a discussion on the subject.

Comment: @Blorgbeard only for the `foreach` loop, not the `for` loop.

Comment: @mikez I'm using the closest equivalent of my code in JavaScript 

    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
     list[i] = function () {
      return i;
     }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
     console.log(list[j]());
    }

Comment: @LukaHorvat: That JS code also prints `4 4 4 4`, since JS does not have block scope.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wrote i instead of j the first time I tried it so it printed the current i of the second for loop.